# Own exposed filter can't use LIKE and REGEXP in one query

Tags: views

I'm working on a own views3 filter which should include wildcard search with '*'. This is working pretty well if you search for one word (for example "test*" or "*test"). But I had the idea to include word search to. Which is, if you type in two words, is searching for both whole words. This is using REGEXP to go for it. All alone, this is also working well. But if I am searching for "test* more", there is no result even if there should be some results. Here's what I am doing so far:
If there is no star in the search word:

```
$placeholder = $this->placeholder();
$this->query->add_where_expression($this->options['group'], "$field REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$searchit."[[:>:]]'");
```

And if there is a star in the search word:

```
$searchstring = explode('*', $searchit);
$placeholder = $this->placeholder();
$this->query->add_where_expression($this->options['group'], "$field LIKE $placeholder", array($placeholder => '%' . db_like($searchstring[1])));
```

Can't drupal handle REGEXP and LIKE in one query? Cause for itself, it is working, as I said before. Or am I doing something wrong.
If the code isn't enough, I could post the whole module.

Comment: Drupal doesn't do anything to your SQL, so if your database engine can handle the query you're throwing at it, then yes, Drupal can too. Best thing you can do is construct a query in plain SQL that you know definitely works, and then start looking for the differences between that and the query Views is generating

Comment: thanks for your tip. I moved from the $placeholder in array form to write the jquery direct, and now it's working. But I didn't change the query itself.